# Instantiate declarative classes in SQLAlchemy without instrumentation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on an application that uses sqlalchemy to pull a lot of data.  The application does a lot of computations on the resulting objects, but never makes any changes to those objects.  The application is too slow, and profiling suggests a lot of the time is spent accessing attributes that are managed by sqlalchemy.  Therefore, I'm trying to figure out how to prevent sqlalchemy from instrumenting these objects.

So far, I've made a little progress based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323267/1572508) and [this example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/_modules/examples/custom_attributes/custom_management.html).  I've found two different ways to do it, but neither one seems to work with relationships.  I'm mostly proceeding by poking around without any comprehensive understanding of the internals of sqlalchemy.  In both cases, I'm using the following test session and data:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
engine.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER, name TEXT)')
engine.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (0, \'Jeremy\')')
engine.execute('CREATE TABLE bar (id INTEGER, foo_id Integer)')
engine.execute('INSERT INTO bar VALUES (0, 0)')
engine.execute('INSERT INTO bar VALUES (1, 0)')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Then I either (1) use a custom subclass of InstrumentationManager:

```
class ReadOnlyInstrumentationManager(InstrumentationManager):
    def install_descriptor(self, class_, key, inst):
        pass

Base = declarative_base()
Base.__sa_instrumentation_manager__ = ReadOnlyInstrumentationManager

class Bar(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))

class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    bars = relationship(Bar)

f = session.query(Foo).first()
print type(f.bars)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.relationships.RelationshipProperty'>
```

instead of the expected list of bars.

Or, (2) use a custom subclass of ClassManager:

```
class MyClassManager(ClassManager):
    def new_instance(self, state=None):
        if hasattr(self.class_, '__readonly_type__'):
            instance = self.class_.__readonly_type__.__new__(self.class_.__readonly_type__)
        else:
            instance = self.class_.__new__(self.class_)
        self.setup_instance(instance, state)
        return instance

Base = declarative_base()
Base.__sa_instrumentation_manager__ = MyClassManager

class ReadonlyFoo(object):
    pass

class ReadonlyBar(object):
    pass

class Bar(Base, ReadonlyBar):
    __tablename__ = 'bar'
    __readonly_type__ = ReadonlyBar
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))

class Foo(Base, ReadonlyFoo):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    __readonly_type__ = ReadonlyFoo
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    bars = relationship(Bar)

f = session.query(Foo).first()
print f.bars
```

which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'ReadonlyFoo' object has no attribute 'bars'
```

Is there a way to modify one of these approaches so that relationships still work?  Or, is there another approach to this problem that's better?

Comment: Yes, using the ORM does have a lot of overhead. Do you *really* need it? If not, can you just bypass it and use the connection directly or use something like pandas which can load DataFrames directly from SQL?

Comment: @reptilicus While it would be theoretically possible to use lower level interactions with SQL directly, the application is much more maintainable if I use sqlalchemy.  Avoiding sqlalchemy's declarative interface would also involve either major rewriting of the application's logic or writing what would essentially be my own custom read-only ORM layer.  The latter is doable (and I've actually experimented with it somewhat successfully), but I'd much rather use sqlalchemy if I can than maintain and debug all that extra code.